# Create Model class and sub items problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Asp.net mvc applications and I need a create page.
My class as ;

```
 public class OrderItemModel
        {
            public OrderItemModel()
            {
                SelectedItems = new List<MenuItem> ;
            }

            public List<MenuItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Notlar { get; set; }
            public string Odeme { get; set; }
        }
```

How can set SelectedItems properties. ? I can't figure out about sub items add.

Have any idea, or example about list properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SelectListItems instead of MenuItem:

```
    public class OrderItemModel
{
    public OrderItemModel()
        {
            SelectedItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

    public List<SelectListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Notlar { get; set; }
    public string Odeme { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your controller do:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    OrderItemModel model = new OrderItemModel() 
    {
        Address = "blah",
        Notlar = "blah",
        Odeme = "blah"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        model.SelectedItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option " + i, Value = i.ToString(), Selected = i == 5 });

    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.OrderItemModel>" %>
...blah blah...
<%= Html.DropDownList("MyDropDown", Model.SelectedItems) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="SelectedItems[0].SomePropOfMenuItem" value="" />
<input type="text" name="SelectedItems[1].SomePropOfMenuItem" value="" />
```